# Grab number from URL and use it as variable in PHP

Tags: php, url, numbers

I'm working from a Wordpress website, and I need to be able to create a template for a real quick-and-simple custom order page.

The plan is to create pages so that the URL of said page will be http://www.website.com/order-1234

And then, the template being used for that page will have PHP in it that will try and grab the "1234" portion of the URL, and use it as a variable.

```
$url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$order_id = intval(substr($url, strrpos($url, '/order-') + 4));
echo $order_id;
```

But the above code is returning a zero "0"

Comment: Shouldn't that +4 be +6 - i.e strlen('/order-')

Comment: Try `+7` - `$order_id = intval(substr($url, strrpos($url, '/order-') + 7));` see phpFiddle - http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/tse-vbr

Comment: actually shouldn't it be +7? Regardless, it should still return "r-1234" -- ahh, the zero is false as it's not a value that can be an int when using "intval()". Try removing that function and see what result you get.

Comment: even  `substr($url,-4);` but you still need to do some checking

Comment: @Dagon wouldn't that limit orders to 4 digits, as it would not work for `order-123` or `order-12345`

Comment: @dmayo - Oops! Yes indeed. Knew there was a reason I showed the reasoning behind the number. Shame I can't count though! :D

Comment: yes it was just of the top of my head

Comment: Hi guys, thanks very much for the quick response. It turns out that the code I used to get the URL won't work. It was giving me the URL for index.php (a wordpress thing, i think). So I used get_permalink instead. @enhzflep I modified your code a bit http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/d1b-rn9

Answer (score 1):

try by using
www.website.com/order?id=1234

and use

```
 $getid = $_GET['id']
```

also when you want to use the get to show the page use the request function

```
 if ($_REQUEST['id'] == $getid) {
 // do something here
}
```

something like that :)

Comment: This works, although some would say that `http://www.website.com/order-1234` looks cleaner/nicer than `http://www.website.com/order?id=1234`

Comment: @Sean you probably right but its the easiest and the fastest way to do it as i know about php so far :P

Comment: Unfortunately, Wordpress won't allow me to manually append "?id=1234" to the permalink url when creating a new page. It takes out the question mark. I could modify the mod_rewrite rules, but this needs to be as simple and quick as possible.